# StringUtils isNumeric returns true when input is "???", why?

Tags: java, apache-stringutils

I was reading the commons.apache.org [`isNumeric`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isNumeric%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) method definition and it states:

```
StringUtils.isNumeric("???") = true;
```

I am not sure why `"???"` is considered to be numeric.  My guesses are:

- A `"?"` is considered a unicode digit
- It is some kind of regex pattern

[image: isNumeric Method Definition]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was able to find the answer to this question by looking at the [StringUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html) source code for the isNumeric method.
In the source code that line appears as:

```
StringUtils.isNumeric("\u0967\u0968\u0969")  = true
```

Where u0967, u0968, u0969 are [Devangari Digits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devanagari#Unicode) one, two, and three respectively.
This may be a browser issue causing the characters to not be rendered correctly in the API.

Comment: And for what it's worth, my browser displays presumably-correct glyphs for those digits, rather than subbing in question marks.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the code, the example is

```
StringUtils.isNumeric("\u0967\u0968\u0969")  = true
```

`\u0967` is `१`, which is "Devanagari Digit One"

`\u0967` is `२`, which is "Devanagari Digit Two"

So they are digits!